# What do I lose when aborting from the Plains of Eidolon?

Tags: warframe

If I'm out on the Plains after finishing a bounty and collecting some resources, it would be nice if I could just teleport back to Cetus, rather than having to run all the way back to the door. I'm worried that choosing to abort the mission will make me lose some or all of my rewards.

What exactly do you lose when you choose to Abort Mission in the Plains of Eidolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose your pickups and bonus XP when you abort a mission.

If you're annoyed by the long journey back to extraction, use the [archwing launcher](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Archwing_Launcher) or a warframe that can travel quickly, like Nova (see [Worm Hole](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Worm_Hole) for example).  There are builds for fast travel in the plains of Eidolon.

If you're stuck because you're in a squad where no one wants to extract, you can leave the squad to be put in your own instance, and then leave using the extraction at any time.

Comment: With Fortuna, you can now use a _hoverboard_ if you don't have the archwing launcher! It's not only fast, but great fun as well.

Answer (score 1):

You lose everything that you have gained after the completed bounty.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this? I've seen conflicting information about this issue on Reddit and the Wikia's forums.

Comment: Experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't lose anything, just the mision resume does not show you what you got but if you take a look at your affinity and your inventory you can see it.