# Can I leave all endless missions, while in a party, just by leaving the squad, and still get all extraction perks, like loot, bonus affinity?

Tags: warframe

I saw this answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/338909/1861) which states:

> If you're stuck because you're in a squad where no one wants to extract, you can leave the squad to be put in your own instance, and then leave using the extraction at any time.

Now, this is in response to a question about Plains of Eidolon, but is the above also true for other endless missions?

For instance, when doing defense missions, everybody get to make their own choice every 5 waves, but for instance for survival, at least half the squad have to go to the extraction point to trigger the extraction timer, and this will also pull everybody out of the mission whether they want to leave or not.

But with the above answer, does this mean I can click on my portrait, pick "leave squad", wait for it to reload me into my own instance, and then leave at my own leisure?

I understand I might be an eas(y|ier) prey to all the mobs on the map without my 3 squadmates.

Here's my question in a more direct and clear manner:

**If I leave the squad, one one of these endless missions, and then extract, do I get to keep everything I picked up and get all the extraction perks and bonuses, without severely negatively impacting the squadmates?**

in other words, **If I leave the squad, on one of these endless missions, does it allow me to:**

1. Leave on my own accord, providing extraction is possible at this point (or even just finish the rest of the mission at my own pace)
2. Leave without bothering the rest of the squad, they can continue to play waves after this
3. Leave *with* all loot I've picked up during the mission
4. Get the bonus XP for finishing the mission?

The reason I'm asking is that for these endless missions I was under the impression that leaving the squad was tantamount to abandoning the mission. Arguably, I can't remember if I've actually tried this.

Comment: I understand that "negatively impact" is open to interpretation. I understand that if I am the host, I will trigger a host migration for the other players, which may or may not succeed. I also understand that the squad will lose one member, which might make it harder for them, although if you've played with me you could probably argue that it is harder *with* me than without me but oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2019-3-07, players can extract separately from Survival, Excavation and Defection Missions.

> • Individual Extraction: You can now extract individually from
>   Survival, Excavation and Defection Missions. This means that if one
>   player decides to leave at 10 minutes, the rest of the squad can
>   soldier on!

Simply stand on the extraction point and you will be extracted separately after a 60 second countdown.

Leaving this way allows you to keep all progress and loot aquired so far. 
If they host leaves this way, a host migration will occur and the game will continue for those who stayed.

Source: https://www.warframe.com/news/operation-buried-debts

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that I got it wrong.

The "Leave Squad" seems to be only available in the big open world areas in the game, such as Plains of Eidolon and Orb Vallis.

While in a regular mission, other than those areas, regardless of mission (at least all the ones I tested this weekend), the "Leave Squad" option is not available.

So no, this is not possible.

Comment: This answer should be combined with Andranik's answer for a complete picture of the current setup.  In open world areas, you may leave squad to get your own instance.  In endless missions, there is no way (or reason) to get your own instance, you may stay, or extract at any point after the initial goal is hit (time, extractors, rotations, etc).